# How to continue parsing next file if error occurs

Tags: perl

Some files has some corrupt characters at the last parsing blog, something as such :

```
10.        ╬ε°⌂    ╬ε°⌂  Ä»kε°⌂  ≡,0
   FROM: 10X£↨> ⌂  0£↨> ⌂ ╬ε°⌂   =╨ε°⌂  ¿9╨ε°⌂  ☺
 1483        ☺   0 47¿9╨ε°⌂  280 146 5078 7522 410 6042
```

So i have an error from the Net::IP and the parsing stops. How may i go to the next file if this error occurs ? is there an option where **"or die"** takes me back somewhere instead of ending ?

```
foreach my $wd (@WITHDRAWALS) {

            my $prefix = new Net::IP ($val) or die (Net::IP::Error());


        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `die` builtin throws a fatal exception. Don't use it if you don't want this behaviour. Instead you could create a (non-fatal) warning with the `warn` builtin, and go to the `next` iteration of the loop which skips over the rest of the loop body:

```
...
my $prefix = Net::IP->new($val) or do {
  warn NET::IP::Error;
  next;
};
...
```

The `do { ... }` is used here to group the two statements together.